# th and td width are different

Tags: css, width, css-tables

I am trying to have my table header be static, but whenever I do this the th and the td widths end up changing. I am doing all of this using CSS. The way that I am making the table header static is by making its position fixed.

I have tried setting the th and td widths to be the same, but that doesn't work.

```
#idOfHeader th { width: 20px; }
#idOfBody td { width: 20px; }
```

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use col tag in html

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <col width="100">
  <col width="50">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sekkk/)

Comment: i tried that, even with 0 padding, but for some reason the td still doesn't listen to the widths and the tr doesn't exactly follow the widths that I set. Some are a little bigger.

Comment: Ok, I ended up using `<colgroup></colgroup>` to stylize it, but I do think that col would have worked too. The reason I didn't see any changes was due to me placing it in a different files table that I wasn't looking at >>;; Thank you for your suggestion though! I was hacking at this problem for far too long.

Answer (score 2):

I dont' see why you'd have to use `min-width`, `max-width` or `<col>`. I think the likely cause of the different widths is either that there is content somewhere forcing a cell to be wider than desired, or the `td`s and `th`s have different padding. The total width of a cell is its width plus its padding.

Unless the padding is specified somewhere, the browser's default paddings will be applied and I guess the padding of the `th` is likely to be bigger than that of the `td`

Comment: I think it did have something to do with the paddings, because when I set it to 0 the td ended up being resized to at least be even lol slowly getting there though!

Answer (score 0):

```
th,td{

width:20px;
max-width:20px;
min-width:20px;
}
```

maybe your `padding` makes such difference

Comment: I have tried that, but for some reason the td doesn't want to listen to my css